# Type 1 Hypervisor hardware privileges, make use of host drivers.

Tags: drivers, privileges

I guess a "type 1" hypervisor is one that is running directly on the host's hardware to control the hardware and manage the guest operating systems, so, does that imply that it would be able to make use of the drivers available on the host operating system? Maybe yes.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you're asking? Are you thinking the guest OS if the same type, would be able to use the devices drivers? You can typically make use of attached devices directly in VM's. Things like attached USB, mice, keyboards, are you thinking of that or something else?

Comment: Yes, but are you saying that if they're not the same type, then, it can't?

Comment: Nope the hardware should show up directly in the VM's.